# Can other objects feeling the gravitational effect of a particle that is in a state of superposition cause its wavefunction to collapse?

Tags: gravity, wavefunction, superposition, quantum-measurements

When I feel the slight gravitational pull of one particle that is in a state of superposition and I measure the exact pull at any given instant does the wavefunction collapse? If particle A constantly receives small differences in gravitational pull from particle B isn't particle A constantly observing the position of particle B?

Comment: Duplicate of [Why doesn't gravity act as a measurement?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78155/)